# How to set a key mapping in the modeline?

Tags: key-bindings, modeline

I have a text file where I keep my personal notes. They're structured in a certain way, so I can operate on those notes with vim commands. I would like to map a keyboard shortcut to a specific set of commands, but that mapping should be available only in this file. So I tried writing a modeline at the end of my file, like this:

```
# vim: nmap \a A [a]<ESC>
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work: when opening the file, vim says

```
Error detected while processing modelines:
line  273:
E518: Unknown option: nmap
```

How do I set a mapping that only works in this file? Preferably without writing to .vimrc or another file. Also, my file doesn't have a filetype, it's just text, and the file doesn't have any extension.

Comment: You don't, modelines are run in a restricted sandbox.  You can however set a `filetype` in a modeline, then add your map (with the `<buffer>` qualifier if you want, cf. `:h :map-<buffer>`) to a corresponding `ftplugin` file. The `filetype` __can__ be a made-up name, it doesn't have to be a well-known type.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I was hoping it worked without a filetype, but defining one for my file inspires me to "think of the possibilities". Thank you. Please move your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moving to answers, as requested.

Modelines are run in a restricted sandbox, there is only a limited number of things they can do, and defining keyboard maps is not among those.

You *can* however set a `filetype` in a modeline, then define a map in a corresponding `ftplugin` file.  If you add the `<buffer>` qualifier the map will be defined only for the buffers of that `filetype` (cf. `:h :map-<buffer>`).

Also, the `filetype` doesn't have to be a "well-known" name, a made-up name would work just as well as a well-known one.